# Binding ColumDefinition Width

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, silverlight-5.0

I am creating a Windows 8.1 app using https://slideview.codeplex.com in the Windows 10 with help of Visual Studio 2015.

I have added grid to the design with 1 row and two column. In the first page there is big image and no text and in other pages there is icon and text. So I am putting if 4* in first column for first page and 2* in first for second page all works good but I wanted to make it dynamic in ContentPresenter and then I can assign it from C#.

Kindly somebody help me.

I tried in different way like I put below code in SlideApplicationFrame.cs

```
#region FirstColumnWidth (DependencyProperty)

    /// <summary>
    /// header Image First Column Width
    /// </summary>
    public GridLength FirstColumnWidth
    {
        get { return (GridLength)GetValue(FirstColumnWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FirstColumnWidthProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstColumnWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FirstColumnWidth", typeof(GridLength), typeof(SlideApplicationFrame),
                new PropertyMetadata(new GridLength(4, GridUnitType.Star))); 

    #endregion

    #region ContentFirstColumnWidth (Attached DependencyProperty)

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentFirstColumnWidth =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ContentFirstColumnWidth", typeof(GridLength), typeof(SlideApplicationFrame), new PropertyMetadata(new GridLength(4, GridUnitType.Star)));

    public static void SetContentFirstColumnWidth(DependencyObject o, GridLength value)
    {
        o.SetValue(ContentFirstColumnWidth, value);
    }

    public static GridLength GetContentFirstColumnWidth(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return (GridLength)o.GetValue(ContentFirstColumnWidth);
    }

    #endregion
```

Then I use it in my ContentPresenter Like this

```
<ContentPresenter  library:SlideApplicationFrame.ContentFirstColumnWidth="{TemplateBinding FirstColumnWidth}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

and at the end in style setter

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding library:SlideApplicationFrame.ContentFirstColumnWidth}"/>
```

Whole Style Setter is as below

```
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid  x:Name="GridHeader">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding library:SlideApplicationFrame.ContentFirstColumnWidth}"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

and setting from MainPage.xaml.cs

```
SlideApplicationFrame RootFrame = Window.Current.Content as SlideApplicationFrame;

RootFrame.FirstColumnWidth = new GridLength(4, GridUnitType.Star);
```

Please help me I will be highly appreciated

Comment: Where are you trying to do: **Binding ColumDefinition Width** ?

Comment: I want to do in this line  <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>. Just need some help so I can do myselft

Comment: You mean that you need to bind it to some value from the ViewModel (or code behind) or to some element's value ?

Comment: from code behind or ContentPresenter

Comment: Added an answer with some pointers, if it's not enough or not working let me know and I'll provide some example

Comment: After your edit - I think in this case it might be that the data context is not the one that you expect so the binding is probably returning null value.

Comment: Kindly can you give me example, I will be highly appreciate

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to reproduce the issue now and I'm not sure if what I think is correct. If you have access to the `SlideApplicationFrame` class you could try to do something like: in the constructor - `this.DataContext = this;` and see if it works. But other than that I would need to debug to find out the reason. An advice for debugging - create an empty Converter that doesn't do anything and just returns the value that it gets so that you could put a breakpoint inside and see what is the actual value that is passed, and if it is called at all.

Comment: I update my code with different approach. If you get time please help me

Comment: I've a lot of work to do this week, today I tried your code but it didn't run, and I'm not sure about the setup of this library (and don't have time/need to investigate now). So if you provide working example without anything unnecessary (eg the content presenter part which in my case crashes at runtime) I (or somebody else) am more likely to be able to help.

Comment: If you can give email I can send u full source code

Comment: HI, Sorry for disturbing you lot, I have remove all extra codes

Comment: Don't worry, will try to check it out when I have the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first you have to have in mind that the values of `ColumnDefinition Width` and `RowDefinition Height` are not of type `Double` but of type `GridLength`

And after that there are two scenarios that I can think of:

1. Binding to another element's value
2. Binding to value from the ViewModel or the code behind

**Case 1:**

If You're binding to some value that is `double` you will need to also use a Converter to convert this value to GridLength

**Case 2:**

If You're binding to something in the code you could create the property of type `GridLength` and bind directly, or if the value is `double` again use Converter like in the previous use case.

**Some References on the type**

[GridLength Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

[GridUnitType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype(v=vs.110).aspx)

- Auto - The size is determined by the size properties of the content object.
- Pixel - The value is expressed as a pixel.
- Star - The value is expressed as a weighted proportion of available space.

**Edit - Just a simple example of working binding**

Still didn't manage to find time to recreate your exact situation so I just used `GridView` (as it has also header) - Content is purple, header consists of two grid columns - green and red, green is bound to dependency property defined in main page

**XAML**

```
<Page
    ...
    x:Name="root">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="GridView" >
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="GridHeader" Height="200">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=TestGridLength}"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Background="Red" Grid.Column="0"></Grid>
                            <Grid Background="Green" Grid.Column="1"></Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <GridView Background="Purple">
    </GridView>
</Page>
```

**Code behind**

```
public GridLength TestGridLength
{
    get { return (GridLength)GetValue(TestGridLengthProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TestGridLengthProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TestGridLengthProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TestGridLength",
        typeof(GridLength),
        typeof(MainPage),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));


public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.TestGridLength = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star);
}
```

Comment: As per your suggestion I did some changes but still it did not work. Kindly can you help me. I have already updated my question new codes